# Eclipse - go to class/interface via hyperling without mouse

Tags: java, eclipse, shortcut

the default Eclipse settings is when you are in Java editor and hold Ctrl and go by mouse over a class or interface name, you can click it and go into that class.

Is it possible to do it by keyboard shortcut only, without mouse? Just move cursor to the name and press a shortcut.

I have set it this way for methods (command "Open Implementation" bound to Ctrl+I) but I can't find out how to do it for classes. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move the cursor over the type and hit <kbd>F3</kbd>

Side note: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> opens a small window with all shortcuts and descriptions

Comment: I only add the command bind to F3 (by default) has name "Open Declaration", When:"In Windows", Category: "Navigate".

Answer (score 1):

yes, for sure make the caret on that class and press  <kbd>F3</kbd>

[image]